React Native BackgroundImage only partially shows
My BackgroundImage's have been acting weird lately and not showing the entire image. The problem only happens 5% of the time - the other 95% the images show as expected. I'm using React Native 0.76.2. Any help figuring out what's going on is appreciated.
See how in the top left, there is a small bit of the image? That's the background image that's somehow only showing a small portion. It's supposed to cover the entire screen.

Here's my code:
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  Image,
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';


const gradientDark = require('../../../assets/images/gradient-dark.png');


function Screen() {

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={{uri: imageUrl}}
      resizeMode={'cover'}
      style={{height: '100%', resizeMode: 'cover'}}
    >

      <Image
        source={gradientDark}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
        style={styles.imageGradient}
      />

      <SafeAreaView style={[
        isAndroid ? headerPadding : null,
        {position: 'relative', zIndex: 1}]
      }>
        <ScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          bounces={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
        >
          <View>
            <Text>Body content goes here</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>

      <ImageBackground
        source={gradientDark}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
        style={styles.footer}
      />

    </ImageBackground>
  );
}

export default Screen;


// --

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageGradient: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -10,
    zIndex: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 260,
    transform: [{rotate: '180deg'}],
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  },
  footer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // bottom: -2,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  }
});


First, remove the current  wrapper component.
Now try to use ImageBackground in below mentioned way:
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native

   <ImageBackground source={{uri: imageUrl}} style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill,{zIndex:-1}]}/>

According to your requirement for other image visibility, you should also adjust zIndex.
Your final could look like below:
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  Image,
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';


const gradientDark = require('../../../assets/images/gradient-dark.png');


function Screen() {

  return (
    <>
  <ImageBackground source={{uri: imageUrl}} style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill,{zIndex:-1}]}/>
      <Image
        source={gradientDark}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
        style={styles.imageGradient}
      />

      <SafeAreaView style={[
        isAndroid ? headerPadding : null,
        {position: 'relative', zIndex: 1}]
      }>
        <ScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          bounces={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
        >
          <View>
            <Text>Body content goes here</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>

      <ImageBackground
        source={gradientDark}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
        style={styles.footer}
      />

    </>
  );
}

export default Screen;


// --

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageGradient: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -10,
    zIndex: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 260,
    transform: [{rotate: '180deg'}],
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  },
  footer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // bottom: -2,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  }
});


Hey, thanks for posting this. I tried it out and the same issue still happens from time to time. I think it has something to do with ImageBackground itself in react 0.76.
I did updated my code to use your format though - it is cleaner and better. Thanks.
